# Powershell Error When Returning Collections.Generic.List[String]

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
[Collections.Generic.List[String]]$script:Database = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]
[string]$script:DatabaseFile = "C:\NewFolder\database.csv"

function RunProgram
{
    $script:Database = getCurrentDatabase #errors after this line
}
function getCurrentDatabase
{
    [string[]]$database = Get-Content -Path $script:DatabaseFile
    [Collections.Generic.List[String]]$databaseAsList = $database
    return $databaseAsList
}
```

I get this exception after getCurrentDatabase returns:

```
Cannot convert the "system.object[]" value of type "system.object[]" to type "system.collections.generic.list`1[system.string]"
```

To get the code to work, I need to do this:

```
[Collections.Generic.List[String]]$script:Database = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]
[string]$script:DatabaseFile = "C:\NewFolder\database.csv"

function RunProgram
{
    getCurrentDatabase #this works fine
}
function getCurrentDatabase
{
    [string[]]$database = Get-Content -Path $script:DatabaseFile
    $script:Database = $database
}
```

Why does the first way throw that exception, but the 2nd way doesn't?

EDIT:
I am using PS version 2.0 and C:\NewFolder\database.csv contains this one line:

```
Release Group,Email Address,Template ID,Date Viewed
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your file?

Comment: Hi chappoo, see my edit.

Comment: I tried running your first snippet and it runs without errors (including invoking `RunProgram` and writing `$script:Database` to host)... is that the exact code in your script?

Comment: note, there's a syntax error on line 11 (missing a bracket): `[Collections.Generic.List[String]]$databaseAsList = $database`

Comment: sorry that typo wasn't in my original code.
and yes this is the entire code. Could it be something to do with the fact that I'm using Powershell v2.0?

Comment: Why are you using all these type annotations at the first place? PowerShell is not a static typed language. In my practice, automatic typing was enough almost all the time.

Comment: I just use it for readability (I come from a C# background). I know you don't need them, but they don't hurt either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's something people trip on a lot...
When you output collections from function PowerShell will enumerate them, loosing original type as a part of the process. To prevent it from happening you can use unary comma:

```
function getCurrentDatabase
{
    [string[]]$database = Get-Content -Path $script:DatabaseFile
    [Collections.Generic.List[String]]$databaseAsList = $database
    , $databaseAsList
}
```

Unary comma should prevent PowerShell from enumerating your collection (it actually enumerates collection of one that we've just created using unary comma).

I wrote a [blog post](http://becomelotr.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/unary-comma/) about it a while ago - should help understand it in more detail.

Comment: wow, I'm sure you can understand how unintuitive that would be for programmers who started with C#!

Comment: do you know why my code would have worked for Chappoo? He wrote in the comments below my question that it worked for him.

Comment: I would guess it was PowerShell version: when I tried on v3 it worked just fine, had to test it with `powershell -version 2` to get same errors you got.